# Anyone know a source for translated Time Zone descriptions?

Tags: windows, internationalization, timezone

Does anyone know of a compiled list of translations for the time zone names in Windows? I need all 75 or so of them in German, French and Spanish. Alternatively, how would I use .Net to compile such a list?

Example format: (GMT+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a list of all the time zones in the registry at:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones

Which can be loaded using:

```
ArrayList zones = new ArrayList();

using( RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
    @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones" ) )
{
    string[] zoneNames = key.GetSubKeyNames();

    foreach( string zoneName in zoneNames )
    {
        using( RegistryKey subKey = key.OpenSubKey( zoneName ) )
        {
            TimeZoneInformation tzi = new TimeZoneInformation();
            tzi.Name = zoneName;
            tzi.DisplayName = (string)subKey.GetValue( "Display" );
            tzi.StandardName = (string)subKey.GetValue( "Std" );
            tzi.DaylightName = (string)subKey.GetValue( "Dlt" );
            object value = subKey.GetValue( "Index" );
            if( value != null )
            {
                tzi.Index = (int)value;
            }

            tzi.InitTzi( (byte[])subKey.GetValue( "Tzi" ) );

            zones.Add( tzi );
        }
    }
}
```

Where TimeZoneInformation is just a class which stores the information for easy access.

The description you're looking for is in the Display value.

Comment: This answer seems wrong in a couple of ways.  First, the OP asked for translated names.  Secondly, you could simply use TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones() instead of the code shown.

Answer (score 8):

Get the time zone database from https://iana.org/time-zones or ftp://ftp.iana.org/tz (or the many other source on the web). These will be keyed in UN ISO codes and English country/City names

And then translate them from http://www.unicode.org/cldr/

e.g.

- French   http://unicode.org/cldr/data/common/main/fr.xml
- Spanish  http://unicode.org/cldr/data/common/main/es.xml

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Also, I have a .NET library called [TimeZoneNames](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames) that makes this data easily consumable.

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft Terminology Collection is [available for download](http://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Terminology.aspx) for [non-commercial use](http://www.microsoft.com/about/legal/en/us/IntellectualProperty/Copyright/Default.aspx).