# Is there an Windows API routine for getting the timezone name in English?

Tags: delphi, winapi, timezone, windows-xp-sp3

The Windows `GetTimeZoneInformation` function returns `StandardName` and `DaylightName` members of the resultant TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION structure localized according to the current user default UI language.  I thought I saw somewhere a means of getting the names in English irrespective of the language the users' PC is running (but I can't find it...).

Does anyone know if this can be done?

Comment: AFAIK there is nothing built in, except then keynames in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones are english. Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617011/anyone-know-a-source-for-translated-time-zone-descriptions

Comment: Would SetThreadLocale help ?

Answer (score 1):

Use SetThreadUILanguage.

I can only give a C++ example.

```
LANGID en = MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US);
SetThreadUILanguage(en);

TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION tzi;
GetTimeZoneInformation(&tzi);

MessageBoxW(NULL, tzi.StandardName, tzi.DaylightName, MB_OK);
```