How to get timezones for a country?
In my .NET 8 application, I currently use two libraries, TimeZoneNames and TimeZoneConverter. I see that TimeZoneNames is not actively maintained, and the author recommends using .NET 6+ built-in classes instead.
I need to achieve the following using only standard .NET 8 features:

Get all time zones for a specific country, similar to TimeZoneNames.GetTimeZonesForCountry:
var zones = TZNames.GetTimeZonesForCountry("BR", "pt-BR");


Get a localized display name for a time zone, such as "Москва" in Russian or "Moscu" in Spanish for the Europe/Moscow time zone.


I’ve reviewed available documentation on Microsoft blogs, questions on Stack Overflow but couldn't find a way to do this without 3rd-party libraries like NodaTime. I know that IANA time zones can be grouped by country and that TimeZoneNames uses this feature.
Is there a way to achieve this in .NET 8 without relying on external libraries?

No, that's a quagmire that's best made somebody else's problem.

This question contains the answer to your second question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617011/anyone-know-a-source-for-translated-time-zone-descriptions

I don't think there are enough standard .NET functions that were created for this purpose because it is very particular and specific.
You will probably need to manually create a system yourself and make your own functions for it.
What you can do is probably find a database of timezones and/or translations of languages, or create one yourself and just access that in your code.
